# Split a string and store it as different variables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a string output from MYSQL DB in the following format. Quotes are included.

```
 "Created" to "Quote Sent"
```

How will i save this String as 2 variables using PHP.

```
For Example: $var1 = 'Created'
             $var2 = 'Quote Sent'
```

I tried with explode, but not getting the desired output.

```
 $string = '"Created" to "Quote Sent"';
 $stringParts = explode("to", $string);
 $var1  = $stringParts[0]; 
 $var2 = $stringParts[1];
```

Can please anyone help me on this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do somthing like this:

```
<?php
$str = '"Created" to "Quote Sent"';
$var1 = str_replace('"', "", explode(" to ", $str)[0]);
$var2 = str_replace('"', "", explode(" to ", $str)[1]);
?>
```

Also you told us you tried this, what out put DID you get?

Answer (score 0):

You should only be calling `explode()` once.  And the more appropriate call to trim the double quotes from the string is: `trim()` with a character mask of `"`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iKYNR))

```
$str = '"Created" to "Quote Sent"';
$parts = explode(' to ', $str, 2);
$var1 = trim($parts[0], '"');
$var2 = trim($parts[1], '"');

echo $var1;
echo "\n---\n";
echo $var2;
```

Output:

```
Created
---
Quote Sent
```

---

If you are crazy for a one-liner, you can use regex.

```
[$var1, $var2] = preg_match('~"([^"]+)" to "([^"]+)"~', $str, $out) ? array_slice($out, 1) : ['', ''];
```

or

```
[$var1, $var2] = preg_split('~"( to ")?~', $str, 3, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);  // need to allow 3rd empty element to be found & disregarded
```